# In which language the questions should be asked?

Tags: discussion, questions, language-choice

I see some questions in english and others in portuguese and I'm always in doubt.

The questions should be asked in portuguese, english or whatever?

---

Vejo algumas perguntas em inglês outras em português e sempre fico na duvida.

As perguntas devem ser feitas em português, inglês ou tanto faz?

Answer (score 3):

Searching a little bit more i found the answer in help topics:

https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Should I write in portuguese or english?

**Both languages are accepted.** If you are learning Portuguese, we suggest that you learn by doing and ask in Portuguese, but there is no obligation. When answering a question, we encourage you to answer in the language of the question, if you are able. Don't worry about making a few mistakes: other community members can help with corrections if you are not as strong in that language.

---

Procurando um pouco mais eu encontrei a resposta nos tópicos de ajuda:

https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Devo escrever em português ou inglês?

**Ambas as línguas são aceitas.** Se você está aprendendo português, sugerimos que aprenda fazendo e perguntando em português, mas não há obrigação. Ao responder a uma pergunta, incentivamos você a responder no idioma da pergunta, se você é capaz. Não se preocupe em cometer alguns erros: outros membros da comunidade podem ajudar com as correções se você não for tão forte nessa língua.